# How to add extra javascript to the head section in a Jade-based view in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a Node.js express web app.

The `layout.jade` looks like

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    block extraHeader
  body
    block content
```

My map.jade looks like:

```
extends layout
block extraHeader
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css')
    script(src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js')
block content
    h1= title
    h2= count
    #map
    script.
        var locations = !{JSON.stringify(jsonData)};
        // Create variable to hold map element, give initial settings to map
        var map = L.map('map',{ center: [0, 0], zoom: 7});
        // Add OpenStreetMap tile layer to map element
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
        }).addTo(map);

        // Add JSON to map
        for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            var loc = locations[i];
            L.marker([loc.lat, loc.lng]).addTo(map);
        }
```

I would like to include additional javascript to the  section in head of the map view instead of inline script, e.g.

```
<head>
... ...
<script type="text/javascript">
    // DO SOMETHING
    var foo = 1;
<script>
</head>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

EDIT:
My package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "app_name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "pg-promise": "^8.4.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Jade are you using ? If you are using the previous version of Jade (< 7.0), you can use the filter `:javascript`.

With latest version of Jade (Pug), you can just simply use the `script` tag, for example:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
      // Your code here
```

More on the topic can be found: https://github.com/pugjs/pug

Edited: If you want to include it in the header of the layout, you can just simply move the script a block that is placed inside the header tag, in your case, moving the script tag into `extraHeader` will do it.

Comment: I added details about package.json and jade version is 1.11.0. Does this make any sense? Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer, why can't you just move it inside `extraHeader` block ?

Comment: Thanks. I added the block to the extraHeader and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 'script' tag with a dot after to introduce inline Jvascript.

```
script.
  if (true) {
    alert("this is working")
  }
```

you can use http://html2jade.org/ to see real-time Jade to HTML conversion or vice versa

Comment: Thanks. But what I needed was not inline script. I wanted the script to be in the script section in Head.